# how to skip frames of a long video played in winform picturebox c#

Tags: c#

I am playing a video in a picturebox winform visual stdio using c#.If the video is very long then how can i achieve the effect of shortening the video ie skipping some of the frames at regular interval while the video is being played so that i am able to play the whole video in less time

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. How are you playing the video in a PictureBox? Are you using some library to play the video, or are you writing the code that reads it and plays it back yourself?

Comment: Also, your question creates some kind of paradox, How do you decide the frames that is to be skipped in b/w the playing video ?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to be clear enough.I am using aforge.video.directshow.filevideosource videosource to play the video  which uses a videosource_newframe property to process each of the frames.Now I am stuck with a problem that if the video is too long then my processing task gets completed while the video has not yet finished.Now my aim is to somehow  play the video in less time and i am not sure of the possible ways to get it done.Hope i am able to express myself clearly now.If still i am not successful I will definitelytry to be  more illustrative next timeThnks in advnc!